# How to run gobuster inside a bash script properly? (Invalid URL espace error)

Tags: bash

I'm writing a simple bash script, which runs gobuster inside a bash script. Outside bash it works totally fine, but within the script I'm getting "invalid URL espace" errors for some of the parsings

```
Gobuster v3.0.1
by OJ Reeves (@TheColonial) & Christian Mehlmauer (@_FireFart_)
===============================================================
[+] Url:            http://10.10.112.95:80/
[+] Threads:        10
[+] Wordlist:       common.txt
[+] Status codes:   200,204,301,302,307,401,403
[+] User Agent:     gobuster/3.0.1
[+] Timeout:        10s
===============================================================
2020/06/01 14:41:45 Starting gobuster

[ERROR] 2020/06/01 14:41:52 [!] parse http://10.10.112.95:80/!@#$%^: invalid URL escape "%^"
```

My bash script is as simple as just running gobuster

```
gobuster dir -w common.txt -u $1
```

$1 is the IP address like 10.10.112.95. What goes wrong here and how can I fix it? The wordlist contains special characters. Words from the wordlist without special characters are working. Thanks in advance for the answer!

Comment: What is the content of `IP` variable?

Comment: It is just the IP address as user input, like 10.10.112.95

Comment: Above the code `gobuster` line add `set -x` to enable Bash "kind of" debug mode see if that helps to figure out what cause the escape characters. Also, try putting `"` around the `$1`. `"$1"`.